# How to change Wordpress logo when scrolling (understrap-child theme)

Tags: wordpress, navbar

I'm building a website using understrap-child theme.
What I would like to achieve is my navbar logo (added through Appearance -> Customize) to change into another one when scrolling the page.

In functions.php I've already added a section in order to be able to add a second logo, which I've successfully added in the Appearance -> Customize section.
Here's the code in functions.php:

```
//ADDING NEW LOGO FIELD


function your_theme_customizer_setting($wp_customize) {
    // add a setting 
        $wp_customize->add_setting('your_theme_hover_logo');
    // Add a control to upload the hover logo
        $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'your_theme_hover_logo', array(
            'label' => 'Upload Hover Logo',
            'section' => 'title_tagline', //this is the section where the custom-logo from WordPress is
            'settings' => 'your_theme_hover_logo',
            'priority' => 8 // show it just below the custom-logo

        )));
    }

    add_action('customize_register', 'your_theme_customizer_setting');
    get_theme_mod( 'your_theme_hover_logo' );
```

Now that I have two logos set, I would like to know how to replace the first logo with the second one when scrolling my page.

Here's my header.php section with the navbar:

```
<!-- ******************* The Navbar Area ******************* -->
    <div id="wrapper-navbar">

        <a class="skip-link sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'understrap' ); ?></a>

        <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top" aria-labelledby="main-nav-label">

            <h2 id="main-nav-label" class="sr-only">
                <?php esc_html_e( 'Main Navigation', 'understrap' ); ?>
            </h2>

        <?php if ( 'container' === $container ) : ?>
            <div class="container">
        <?php endif; ?>

                    <!-- Your site title as branding in the menu -->
                    <?php if ( ! has_custom_logo() ) { ?>

                        <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>

                            <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0"><a rel="home" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" itemprop="url"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>

                        <?php else : ?>

                            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" itemprop="url"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php } else {
                        the_custom_logo();
                    } ?><!-- end custom logo -->
```

Please notice that I've already added a Query in order to change the navbar background color when scrolling...and that works!

```
</script>

<script>jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    jQuery('nav').toggleClass('scrolled', jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 80);


});</script>
```

with its CSS rules:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar.scrolled {
        background-color: $secondary;
        border-bottom: solid rgba(37, 36, 36, 0.055);
```

I really hope you can help me solve my problem! 
THANK YOU SO MUCH!!